# Start multiple Nuxtjs projects with pm2 on Digital Ocean

Tags: pm2

I have several projects inside a Digital Ocean Droplet proxied with nginx and i want to start all of them with pm2, i saw i can achieve that with a .json file with the names and scripts inside, but it doesn't seem to be working, this is what i did:

**My droplet directory with the projects:**

project1

project2

pm2-apps.json

**pm2-apps.json**

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "script": "./project1/package.json"
    },
    {
      "name": "project2",
      "script": "./project2/package.json"
    },
  ]
}
```

then i run

```
pm2 start pm2-apps.json
```

and i get

[image]

but then i enter the url, the project doesnt seem to be correctly mounted, if i run each one apart with `pm2 start npm -- start` inside the project folder, it works.

Comment: shouldn't it be `"script":` not `"scripts":`

Comment: fixed that but still not working

Comment: confirm the apps are running `pm2 monit`, `netstat -pant`, `top` etc then try wget them.. then you should check its not your nginx proxy setup.

Comment: I setted up the project with this tutorial: https://medium.com/codeartisan/how-to-run-nuxt-js-on-digitalocean-159fc558d2ab, and when i run each project separated, they work fine

Comment: i just can't achieve to run them both with one single process

Comment: sorry misread, I thought was having issues starting them. If you have two separate nuxt projects its going to run multiple processes, it does not combine them like for example in PHP world, thats not how node works (thankfully).

Comment: That is in fact the problem (i explained myself wrong i guess), when i run the script, the projects don't mount, i go to the url and it show a 502 error, that happens when i fetch the url and the project is not mounted on the server, by one single process i wanted to say multiple process through one single config file (pm2-apps.json in this case). if i go to the project1 folder and run pm2 start npm -- start it works, but that way i can't run the other project, just one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to test this, and found a couple of issue you might be having, presuming you have nginx is correctly setup.

I had to change the file to the following:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "project1",
      "cwd": "./project1",
      "script": "/usr/bin/npm",
      "args": "run dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "project2",
      "cwd": "./project2",
      "script": "/usr/bin/npm",
      "args": "run dev"
    }
  ]
}
```

oddly `"script": "npm",` was not enough as was SIGINT'ing which I could see from using `pm2 monit`

then in each of the projects, I changed the nuxt port:

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  ...
  server: {
    port: 3001, // project1
    host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
  },
  ...
```

and

```
  ...
  server: {
    port: 3002, // project2
    host: '0.0.0.0', // default: localhost
  },
  ...
```

then clear out pm2.. `pm2 delete all`

then run from within the folder:

```
pm2 start pm2-apps.json
```

Both apps then start without issue..

[image]

Comment: it works perfectly, i just changed the args to start instead run dev